# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns of a table having exception while resultSet.next() i.e ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

While getting metadata of a table that have columns like type object.
when calling DatabaseMetaData.getColumns and iterating over resultset using next method has exception

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
private void searchForColumnNameInTables(DatabaseMetaData dmd) throws SQLException {
    Iterator iter = listOfTables.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String tableName = (String) iter.next();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs1 = dmd.getColumns(catalog, schema, tableName, "%"); //
        //java.sql.ResultSet rs1 = dmd.getUDTs(tableName, schema, "%", null);
        while (rs1.next()) {
            String colName = rs1.getString(4);
            String colType = rs1.getString(5);
            System.out.println("Table " + tableName + " ColumnName" + colName + " ColumnType" + colType);
            if (colName.trim().toLowerCase().equals(colNameToSearchFor)) { //
                System.out.println("found '" + colNameToSearchFor + "' in " + tableName);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Oracle's JDBC driver. Which driver version are you using (note: the number in the filename is **not** the driver version, it's the targeted **Java** version)

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in [JDBC driver 12.1.0.2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0urLP3bHhAhWSlxQKHZF3DCcQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.oracle.com%2Fknowledge%2FMiddleware%2F2184878_1.html&usg=AOvVaw2JvQdmbFhEN0NRhF6VrXti). Upgrade to 12.2.0.1 or contact your Oracle support.